# Is there any way to get information about current session from gv$session in oracle?

Tags: oracle, session, oracle-rac

Is there any way to uniquely identify current session in `GV$SESSION` view in Oracle?

I've faced with the problem that the following query may return more than one row in case of Oracle RAC configuration:

```
SELECT SID, SERIAL#
FROM GV$SESSION
WHERE AUDSID = Sys_Context('USERENV', 'SESSIONID')
   AND SID = Sys_Context('USERENV', 'SID');
```

Using `V$MYSTAT` is not an option either, because `V$MYSTAT` may not be accessible for the current session (for example when statistic is disabled).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SID, SERIAL#
FROM V$SESSION
WHERE AUDSID = Sys_Context('USERENV', 'SESSIONID');
```

Since you're interested in current session, the current session must be on the local instance (by definition), so use `V$SESSION` instead of `GV$SESSION`.  Also, all you need is `AUDSID` to uniquely identify your session.

If you've got some reason you *really* need to use `GV$SESSION` (can't imagine why that would be), you could do this instead:

```
SELECT SID, SERIAL#
    FROM GV$SESSION
    WHERE AUDSID = Sys_Context('USERENV', 'SESSIONID')
      AND INST_ID = USERENV('Instance');
```

Also, an alternate way to get the `SID` of the current session is:

```
select sid from v$mystat where rownum=1;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately both options cannot be used in my case (I've explicitly mentioned that in my question). `AUDSID` plus `SID` is not unique in case of Oracle RAC (only combination of `SID` and `SERIAL#` is unique) and `V$MYSTAT` is unavailable because statistics is turned off.

Comment: I missed the comment about V$MYSTAT, sorry.  BTW, I don't think it's true.  I haven't tested, but I suspect that V$MYSTAT is always present.  But I don't see anything about not being able to use V$SESSION instead of GV$SESSION.  However, if you really can't use V$SESSION for some crazy reason, then use the query I have above, but change it backto GV$, and then add one additional predicate, "and inst_id = userenv('Instance')".  That's the same predicate Oracle uses in the definition of a V$ view.

Comment: As I've said above, both V$SESSION and GV$SESSION may yield more than one row in Oracle RAC configuration, when filtered by only `AUDSID` and even by combination of `AUDSID` plus `SID`. `AUDSID` may not be unique. Only combination of `SID` plus `SERIAL#` is unique, but how to get `SERIAL#` of current session?

Comment: But `inst_id = userenv('Instance')` may do the trick. Could you please add it as a separate answer? I'll test it and mark as correct if it works.

Comment: I edited the answer above, as, when I went to add a new answer, the system strongly encouraged me to edit and improve my existing answer, rather than add a new answer.

Comment: select user from dual will not work

Answer (score 1):

Joining `gv$session` and `v$mystat` :)

```
 SELECT SID, SERIAL#,inst_id
  FROM GV$SESSION
 WHERE sid=(select sid from v$mystat where rownum=1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `V$SESSION` instead of `GV$SESSION`

```
SELECT SID, SERIAL#
FROM V$SESSION
WHERE SID = Sys_Context('USERENV', 'SID');
```

Comment: `V$SESSION` in not producing unique `SID` and `SERIAL#` in case of RAC installation

Comment: @VolodymyrFrolov The other way around. GV$SESSION gives you all sessions of every node, and SID can be not unique in that view. V$SESSION gives you only the sessions of your current node, and in that context the SID is unique, so if you query your session id from that view (`Sys_Context('USERENV', 'SID')`), you will get your session, and not accidentally somebody else's session that happens to have the same SID.

Comment: See also [RAC V$ vs GV$ views](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rac_v$_gv$_views.htm)

That said, I'm not sure why I added this answer three years after Mark J. Bobak added his, which has the same information and more.. 

Answer (score 0):

Try this (will need access to v$session and v$sql views) -

```
select /*My Sess*/ 'My Sess Text = hello world @ '||systimestamp SID_SR_TXT from dual
union
select 'SID = '||sid||' Serial# = '||serial# SID_SR_TXT  from v$session where sql_id in 
(select sql_id from v$sql where sql_text like '% My Sess %');
```

Comment: This is not going to work if there's some other session which tries to find itself in the same manner. Instead of "My Sess" there must be some unique identifier.