# SQLAlchemy session object get oracle v$session sid, serial

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

Using python and SQLAlchemy sessions with an Oracle database, is it possible to get info about the corresponding Oracle v$session such as the sid or serial# from the session object? I could not find any mention of a sid or serial# in the session documentation here 
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/sessions.html

Comment: Trivial filter is based on `USERNAME, MACHINE, OSUSER`, which will by sufficient if you use e.g. a dedicated DBUSER for SQLAlchemy. Otherwise you will need to *instrument* your sessions by setting one or more of `module, action, client_identifier` which you should achieve via `cx_oracle` e.g. [Connection.client_identifier](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/6.4/connection.html#Connection.client_identifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For its Oracle dialect, SQLAlchemy [uses cx_oracle](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/oracle.html), which [offers some limited access to v$session through the Connection object](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/6.1/connection.html). I don't think you can view the sid or serial#, though?

However, you can look up the sid,serial# for the current session using SQL. [Try this query from a similar question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28815685/3061852)

```
SELECT SID, SERIAL#
FROM V$SESSION
WHERE AUDSID = Sys_Context('USERENV', 'SESSIONID');
```